# XML::LibXML remove heading when write to xml

Tags: xml, perl, xml-libxml

When I update value with XML::LibXML the first two lines are removed.
I want to preserve the xml as is, except one updated value.

My original xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
 <property>
   <name>test.name</name>
   <value>help</value>
   <description>xml issue</description>
 </property>
```

....

And the code is:

```
my $parser =XML::LibXML->new();
my $tree   =$parser->parse_file($file) or die $!;
my $root   =$tree->getDocumentElement;

my $searchPath="/configuration/property[name=\"$name\"]/value/text()";
my ($val)=$root->findnodes($searchPath);

$val->setData($new_val);
open (UPDXML, "> $file") or die "ERROR: Failed to write into $file...";
 print UPDXML $root->toString(1);
close (UPDXML);
```

I tried with print UPDXML $root->toStringC14N(1) but it does not help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both daxim and rpg answers do that, but to emphasize - use `$tree->toString()` instead of `$root->toString()` to get whole file.

Answer (score 3):

See [`toFile` in XML::LibXML::Document](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML%3a%3aDocument#toFile). Do read the documentation of the software you're working with.

```
use strictures;
use XML::LibXML qw();
my $file    = 'fnord.xml';
my $name    = 'test.name';
my $new_val = 'foo';

my $parser  = XML::LibXML->new;
my $tree    = $parser->parse_file($file);
my $root    = $tree->getDocumentElement;

my $searchPath  = "/configuration/property[name='$name']/value/text()";
my ($val)       = $root->findnodes($searchPath);

$val->setData($new_val);
$tree->toFile($file);
```

The file routines automatically raise exceptions, no need for the traditional Perl error checking.

Comment: 10x. The cpan states that it's the same as toString but good when working with a large file, so I did not try it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
$tree->toFile ($file);
```